# Extracting October Static Pages MainMenu items for a Vue.js app

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

For building a Vue menu in October, I have the following code in a backend plugin. It is working fine to get the ***Static Pages*** **pages** in a JSON data, keeping the pages items indentation :

```
$theme = \Cms\Classes\Theme::getEditTheme();
$pageList = new \RainLab\Pages\Classes\PageList($theme);
$treePageList = $pageList->getPageTree(true);
```

Now I would like to extract the October "RainLab Static Pages / Menus / **Mainmenu**" **items**, keeping the menu items indentation. (In my backend plugin).

Thanks for any idea about how to get these menu items ?

[image]

Comment: You can create your own plugin and call static pages' menu component. Turn that information to a json() response.

Comment: Thanks Pettis, bu I already created a plugin for that. My question was about how to "query" the static pages component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hardik Satasiya, I solved it with the following code :

```
if(class_exists('\\Rainlab\\Pages\\Classes\\Menu')) {
    $theme = \Cms\Classes\Theme::getActiveTheme();
    $menus = \RainLab\Pages\Classes\Menu::listInTheme($theme, 'mainmenu');
    $menu_full = json_decode($menus);

    return getRecursiveMenu($menus);
}

function getRecursiveMenu($menus) {
    static $level = 0;
    static $next_level = 0;
    $menuDetails = [];
    foreach($menus as $iMenu) {
        $detail = [];
        if ($level == $next_level) {
            $detail['menu_name'] = ['name' => $iMenu->name];
        } else
            $detail['menu_name'] = ['title' => $iMenu->title, 'url' => $iMenu->reference];

        $level++;
        $items = getRecursiveMenu($iMenu->items);

        if(count($items) > 0 ) {
            $detail['menu_items'] = $items;
        }
        $menuDetails[] = $detail;
        $next_level++;
    }
    return $menuDetails;
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: sure mate , i am glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You could add `static-menu component` and `ajax-handler` on your `layout file` to handle ajax request.

> Your need to add `staticMenu` with proper `menu selected`

Now in handler code

```
function onGetMenu() {
    $menuItems = $this['staticMenu']->menuItems();
    return Response::json(['mainMenu' => $menuItems]);
}
```

> Ajax request

```
$.request('onGetMenu', {
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and you can have your menu in response

if you want to look full tutorial with images please checkout here
[Static Page Menu Ajax Tutorial](https://tutorialmeta.com/october-cms/how-to-get-static-page-menu-items-using-ajax)

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thanks Hardik for this fine answer. I modified my post to clarify, but I would like to run it in my backend plugin. Do I need Ajax request, or is it for a frontend request ?

Comment: means you just need to query it or you need to query it by ajax

Comment: @Incremental can you check this may be this can help you : https://tutorialmeta.com/blog/post/how-to-get-static-page-menu-items-using-ajax#5